# What is $x^{1/2} + x^{-1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Would these two terms cancel out and be zero or can they not be put together since technically the exponent is different?

EDIT:
I am working on $x^{1/2} + x^{-1/2}$ not $x^{1/2} = x^{-1/2}$

Comment: are you saying $x^{1/2}=x^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Hint: multiply both sides by $x^{1/2}$.

Comment: *Would these two terms cancel out and be zero ?* - You seem to be confusing exponentiation with multiplication.

Comment: Does it help you to rewrite it as $\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: Did you bother to try inserting even a single value for $x$ before asking this question?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. This is as simple as it gets! You can only put together things of different exponents if you're *multiplying* them.

Comment: How would I do that in this instance?

Comment: You can only combine exponents if you have this situation: $A^n \cdot A^m = A^{m+n}$. Since you have a plus sign between both $x$'s, you can't add the exponents together.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, positive exponents do not necessarily mean that it is positive, and negative exponents do not necessarily mean that it is negative. Negative exponents require you to take the reciprocal of the expression to make it positive. Fractional exponents require you to calculate the value of the variable to the power of the numerator, then evaluate that to the $n$'th root of the denominator. It is way easier to explain if I actually write down the formulas.
To calculate fractional exponents:
$$x^\frac{m}{n} = \sqrt[n]{x^m}$$
A similar formula may be used:
$$x^\frac{m}{n} = (\sqrt[n]{x})^m$$
To calculate negative exponents:
$$x^{-m} = \frac{1}{x^m}$$ 
So, the expression $x^\frac{1}{2} + x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ can be simplified like so:
$$x^\frac{1}{2} + x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=\sqrt[2]{x^1} + \frac{1}{x^\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$=\sqrt[2]{x^1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[2]{x^1}}$$
$$=\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
How would we combine the two? We could make $\sqrt{x}$ have the common denominator, which is also $\sqrt{x}$, by multiplying both numerator and denominator of the fraction by $\sqrt{x}$.
$$\frac{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}}{1\cdot\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
You could even simplify the expression further by **rationalizing** it. This simply removes the square root from the denominator, and is done because we do not like to see square roots at the bottom of the fraction, just like how we do not like to see fractions in the standard form of linear graphs $Ax + By + C = 0$. To rationalize the fraction, we could multiply it by the fraction $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$.
$$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x}\cdot(x+1)}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{(x+1)^2}}{x}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x(x+1)^2}}{x}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x(x^2+2x+1)}}{x}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x^3+2x^2+x}}{x}$$
**Final Answer:**
$$x^\frac{1}{2} + x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{\sqrt{x^3+2x^2+x}}{x}$$
This shows that the terms do not cancel out. You have to remember that:
$$x^{-m} \neq -x^{m}$$
Instead:
$$x^{-m} = \frac{1}{x^m}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: When is it true that $y=\frac 1y$?

Answer (score 1):

Other hints to work with this expression are that you can collect $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and obtain
$$x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+x^{-1})$$
or put a minimun common denominator 
$$x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}=\frac{x+1}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}.$$

These all show that what you obtain do not cancel out, so neither do the first terms.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d=\sqrt{x}+\frac1{\sqrt{x}} \Rightarrow d\sqrt{x}=x+1 \Rightarrow d^2x=(x+1)^2 \rightarrow d^2=\frac{(x+1)^2}{x}$.
Thus
$$d=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x}}$$